# Trying to combine wire with lightning-datatable to obtain field labels

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, language

What I am trying to accomplish: in a multi-language org, I want to have a datatable in a Lightning Web Component that uses the field labels as defined in Salesforce, so that the proper labels are displayed for users in all supported languages. For custom labels I have managed to do this. But for field labels I can't get this to work.

My code (I have tried this for one field so far):

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
      <div class="slds-col slds-p-vertical_xx-small">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="sId"
                data={searchResults}
                columns={searchResultColumns}
                hide-checkbox-column="true"
                suppress-bottom-bar="true">
        </lightning-datatable>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import PRICESTOCKRESULT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/PriceStockResult__c';

export default class TradeWindow extends LightningElement {

    @track searchResultColumns = [];
    @track searchResults;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PRICESTOCKRESULT_OBJECT } )
    priceStockResultInfo({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.searchResultColumns = [
                    { label: data.fields.ItemId__c.label, fieldName: 'artikelcode', fixedWidth: 120 },
                    { label: 'Artikelnaam', fieldName: 'artikelnaam', editable: true },
                    { label: 'Gestopt', fieldName: 'gestopt', type: 'boolean', fixedWidth: 67 },
                    { label: 'GIP', fieldName: 'gip', type: 'currency', fixedWidth: 85 },
                    { label: 'Marge', fieldName: 'marge', type: 'percent', typeAttributes: { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }, fixedWidth: 80 },
                    { label: 'Eenheidsprijs', fieldName: 'eenheidsprijs', type: 'currency', fixedWidth: 118 },
                    { label: 'Korting %', fieldName: 'kortingPercentage', type: 'percent', typeAttributes: { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }, fixedWidth: 100 },
                    { label: 'Verkoopsprijs', fieldName: 'verkoopsprijs', type: 'currency', fixedWidth: 120 },
                    { label: 'Har', fieldName: 'harVoorraad', type: 'number', fixedWidth: 60 },
                    { label: '#Har', fieldName: 'harBestellen', type: 'number', editable: true, fixedWidth: 65 },
                    { label: 'Bay', fieldName: 'bayVoorraad', type: 'number', fixedWidth: 60 },
                    { label: '#Bay', fieldName: 'bayBestellen', type: 'number', editable: true, fixedWidth: 65 },
                    { label: 'Fysiek geres.', fieldName: 'fysiekGereserveerd', type: 'number', fixedWidth: 112 },
                    { label: 'Klantbest.', fieldName: 'klantbestelling', type: 'number', fixedWidth: 100 },
                    { label: 'In bestelling', fieldName: 'inBestelling', type: 'number', fixedWidth: 110 }
                ];      
        }
    }
}
```

The result is a screen with an empty datatable (obviously, because there is no data), but also with an empty table header.

This could be caused by the fact that priceStockResultInfo is not used directly in the markup, so that wire is not activated. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to import a wire method that doesn't exist. The import line should be:

```
import { getObjectInfo  } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```

Comment: Yes, that is the one. Stupid me. Thanks! And now I run into the problem that the label is not shown in the proper language. But that is another thing... Two steps forward, one step back.

Comment: And the problem of the labels displaying in the wrong language was a browser cache issue. Multiple times Ctrl-F5 didn't fix that, but a stop+start did (Chrome).